# Android Studio 3.0 Canary 5 - Error:Unable to load class 'org.gradle.api.internal.component.Usage'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have read through all of the existing stack questions relating to this and their solutions did not help me.

- This problem has been evident since all AS updates above 2.3.
- Creating a new project is ok and builds
- I've attempted to copy all values from the 'new project' but it still persists

The error:

> Error:Unable to load class 'org.gradle.api.internal.component.Usage'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's
>     dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network
>     connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies
>     and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle
>     build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may
>     solve this problem. Stop Gradle build
>     processes (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a
>     third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in
>     the project or the version of Gradle requested by the
>     project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can
>   also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME 
distributionPath=wrapper/dists zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-milestone-1-all.zip
```

Project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha5'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:0.89.1"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Settings Gradle

```
Use default gradle wrapper
```

Module Settings

```
Compile Sdk Version: API 26
Build Tools Version: 26.0.0
```

I believe these are all the latest available.
And I have tried invalidate caches & restart / rebooting the machine

Comment: https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin/issues/43

Comment: I'm not sure how that is related, nor did I find a solution in there? Any comment in particular that you think I should be reading? All of my versions are greater than the one's mentioned in that thread.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I tried all the above suggestions for deleting cache and nothing worked for me.  In the end, the problem was the plugin `com.novoda:bintray-release:0.4.0`.  When I upgraded it to `0.5.0`, it worked.

I would take a hard look at your gradle plugins!

Comment: Nice same was the issue with me

Comment: Ha! I was so skeptical because I didn't use bintray but did a project search and it was in one of the libraries I had obtained the source of instead of the dependency, and it was in fact using a very old version of bintray. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Delete Gradle cache `C:/users/<yourname>/.gradle` (delete the whole directory actually). Then upgrade Gradle and try again.

Or if you are using Gradle wrapper go into properties and upgrade the version of the wrapper `./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

Your question doesn't specify the versions, then I assume this might be your problem.

**Edit:** Check if your plugins are still Compatible with your version of Gradle

`io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:0.89.1` seems a bit old there is a version `3.5.0` already

Since `Gradle 3.4` `Usage` was renamed to `UsageContext` and maybe one of your plugins, or dependencies is not compatible with `Gradle 4.1-milestone` that you are using by looking at the distribution Url.

Comment: Wow 8GB worth, but the problem still occurred after opening AS after the deletion. What 'versions' were you referring to, I tried to list everything possible and can't think of any other versioning related to this

Comment: @behelit Gradle version, or Gradle wrapper version, maybe your AS is not happy with the Gradle version. And I said to delete the folder and then update Gradle with a newer version, not just delete it, but now i see you are using `4.1-milestone` did you tried to do what it suggested? did you check if `io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:0.89.1` is compatible with the newest version of Gradle?

Comment: In my case i got the code working with the following line : https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-bin.zip.